# How to change Button and Textblock style on binding

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

I'm trying to change the style of a button as well as the style of a textblock included in the button via a binding without success.
I want to get something like this:

[image][image]

I want change the TextBlock foreground color and the Button BorderThickness according to the binding.

Here is my code :

```
<Button Name="WeldHistory"
Margin="20,0,20,0"
VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
Height="auto"
Background="{x:Null}"
BorderBrush="{StaticResource RedPolysoudeNormalBrush}"
BorderThickness="0 0 0 3"
Command="{Binding ScreenWeldHistoryCommand}" >
<Button.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Static lang:UI_Text.SCREEN_PROGRAM_LIBRARY}" Typography.Capitals="AllSmallCaps" Typography.CapitalSpacing="True">
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsWeldHistoryActive}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="red"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</Button.ContentTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem should be with the Binding which you are making with `IsWeldHistoryActive`. Can you try with binding to the `Button`'s `DataContext` ?

```xml
<TextBlock.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.IsWeldHistoryActive, 
                                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button, 
                                                   Mode=FindAncestor}}" 
                         Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</TextBlock.Style>
```